# How to use sbt and ivy2 cache in Docker containers run in Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: docker, sbt, ivy, bitbucket-pipelines

BB Pipelines let you keep SBT and Ivy caches between builds:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/caching-dependencies-895552876.html

and you can have Docker service to run containers dynamically from your tests: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/run-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines-879254331.html

Nevertheless, if you try to run a container using caches downloaded in the build setup step, namely these:

```
Cache "sbt": Downloading
...
Cache "ivy2": Downloaded 363.2 MiB in 9 seconds
Cache "ivy2": Extracted in 2 seconds
```

in your step with Docker service, defined in `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` similar to

```
  - step:
      name: My integration steps with Docker
      image: docker/compose:1.24.0
      size: 2x
      caches:
        - sbt
        - ivy2
      services:
        - docker
      script:
        - docker run -it -v ~/.ivy2:/root/.ivy2 alpine sh -c 'ls ~/.ivy2'
```

you get an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: authorization denied by plugin pipelines: -v only supports $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR and its subdirectories.
```

Copying `~.ivy2` to the clone directory doesn't look like an elegant solution. Which is the supposed way to use these caches within your own Docker images running on BB Pipelines?